# How to override/replace the related field from base in odoo 9

Tags: overriding, odoo-9, account

Existing Field(base addons):

```
journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', related='statement_id.journal_id', string='Journal', store=True, readonly=True)

New Field(custom addons):

journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal',string='Journal')
```

I want to change the existing field into new field like above example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code...

```
journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal', 

related='statement_id.journal_id', string='Journal', store=True, readonly=True)

New Field(custom addons):

journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal',string='Journal',related=False,store=False, readonly=False)
```

Comment: related=False is working, tried in odoo 13

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new addon with a model that inherits from the model you want to override. Then just define the field as you wish.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'other.model'

    journal_id = fields.Many2one('account.journal',string='Journal')
```

Comment: Actually i tried this solution. But its not affecting.

Comment: You might have to manually remove the relation in postgresql. I think I have seen this before. Odoo fails to tell postgresql to remove the relation